# Why does Bridge.net not compile HashSet<T> or Stack<T>

Tags: c#, bridge.net

I am using Bridge.net v17.10.1, and according to the documentation they are implemented in Bridge.Core.

```
HashSet<T> varName;
Stack<T> varName2;
```

Produces the following errors:

```
Error   CS0433  The type 'HashSet<T>' exists in both 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'Bridge, Version=17.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'


Error   CS0433  The type 'Stack<T>' exists in both 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'Bridge, Version=17.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Probably something super simple, but my Bridge.Net knowledge is limited and I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, the answer is described here: https://forums.bridge.net/forum/community/help/2902-c-compile-error-the-type-stopwatch-exists-in-both-system-and-bridge

> Yes, you have to remove System reference from your csproj file
> Also I can suggest to add the following reference to prevent adding System reference by Visual Studio

```
<Reference Include="System" Condition="False" />
```

Comment: Bridge.HashSet<T> is not correct.  The class is System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>.  Take a look at what Bridge.Net is.  Is is not a simple library of classes, but a method for compiling c# to javascript.The intent is to use the original HashSet class

Comment: I figured it out. You need to work with the forum's described workaround